# Chaining apollo retryLink and errorLink

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-link

Should Apollo `retryLink` come before or after the `errorLink`? Some examples show it as before https://medium.com/@joanvila/productionizing-apollo-links-4cdc11d278eb#3249 while some show it after https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-rest/#link-order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how you want your `errorLink` logic to work, from the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/#composing-a-link-chain)

> Additive composition involves combining a set of links into a serially executed chain

and the [Error Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-error)

> is called after the GraphQL operation completes and execution is moving back **up** your link chain

so if you place the `retryLink` before the `errorLink`

```js
ApolloLink.from([retryLink, errorLink])
```

the `errorLink` will also be executed with the retries once the respective result is traveling back up the [chain](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction), in other words (if you are using the default docs example), there should be a console log on every attempt and [`attempts.max`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-retry#optionsattempts) console logs in total.

In case the order is flipped the `errorLink` will be called after the `retryLink` is complete and the result traveled all the way back up, so there should be 1 console log from the `errorLink` call.